# Javascript: однократный вызов функции - (определение функции и вызов функции) в одну строчку

Tags: javascript, функции, параметры

Приветствую

Стоит задача однократно вызвать функцию. Можно ли это сделать (определение функции и вызов функции) в одну строчку?

Сейчас у меня сделано следующим образом:

```
function get(value)
{
    return result;
}

const data = get(15);
```

Можно задать так:

```
const get = function(value)
{
    return result;
}

const data = get(15);
```

А можно ли сделать сразу вызов и определение, типа такого

```
const data = (15)
{
    return result;
};
```

(не знаю как тут точно это показать :))

Comment: Для чего вообще помещать в функцию код, выполняемый в том же месте и однократно?

Comment: @yar85 для визуального удобства, чтобы начинка была внутри {}, а все внешние переменные - снаружи

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как я понял, вам нужно вот такой вызов функции. Для того, чтобы функция выполнилась при инициализации, нужно обернуть ее в скобки, а после в новых скобках указать параметры функции, или оставить их пустые.

```js
(function (value) {
  console.log(value)
})(15);
```

Если вас интересует однократный вызов функции, то вам подойдет первый случай, во втором случае рассмотрен случай, если вам необходимо привязать эту функцию к какому-либо обработчику событий, так как обратиться к такой функции из глобальной области видимости нельзя.

```js
var eventHandler = function functionName() {
  alert('Вызов функции');
  return functionName;
}();

document.getElementById('button').onclick = eventHandler;
```

```html
<button id="button">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: то что надо!
и ведь скорее всего раньше что-то подобное использовал, но забыл :)

Comment: единственное, как я понимаю, можно не указывать имя функции, потому что до него всё равно не достучаться

Comment: В первом случае можно и без имени обойтись (поправил ответ), а во втором как раз таки можно достучаться, если есть необходимость, там надо.